# Sports: opposite of an upset

Tags: antonyms, sports

What's the opposite of an upset in sports.  Maybe "expected outcome"...

Terser would be better, but I'd hear anything that came to mind.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a terse alternative, you might describe an *expected outcome* as a *given*. (The word "given" is commonly accepted a noun in modern English.)

Consider the following two sentences:

> The result of that game was an upset.
>
> The result of that game was a given.

They both sound pretty natural, and I would certainly consider them decent single-word antonyms.

Answer (score 0):

The expression I would use is **in line.** "The result was in line (with expectations)."